# OpenShift node alpine Image - npm doesn't work

Tags: npm, openshift, alpine-linux

I'm experiencing a very weird scenario with a deployment in OpenShift.
If I build the image locally before pushing it to the registry, taking that image to OCP, everything works. However building and pushing the image through a CI process in Azure Pipelines, causes the pod to die.
After a lot of debugging, I found that the npm module just doesn't do anything, no matter the command you give it. This causes the pod to die and start over when running the npm run start.

In the pod terminal:
[pod terminal behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4uMR.png)

In a docker run locally or oc debug:
[behaviour outside OCP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EiAw.png)

If anyone experience this behaviour or even has some suggestions on what more to try in order to find the cause, Any suggestion can help.

Answer (score 1):

So after a little more digging, I noticed that the node version is different between the previous locally built image an the current images created with the ci. changing the image from node:alpine to node:17.9.0-alipine (17.9.0 is the version in the working image) fixed it for me and now everything works as before :)